# How to I pass multiple parameters from a form to a controller in Asp.net MVC core?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, routes, asp.net-core-mvc

Hi I am trying to take the textboxes from a form and insert them as a parameter in a controller
Here is my Form

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "AddCar";
}

<h1>AddCar</h1>

<form asp-action="AddCar" method="post">
    <div class="text-danger">@Validation.errorMessage</div>

    <label>Make/Model: </label><br />
    <input type="text" name="makeModel" value="Buick" /><br />
    <label>Year: </label><br />
    <input type="text" name="year" value="1998" /><br />
    <label>Color: </label><br />
    <input type="text" name="color" value="Red" /><br />
    <label>Price: </label><br />
    <input type="text" name="price" value="123123" /><br />
    <label>Milage: </label><br />
    <input type="text" name="milage" value="112312" /><br />
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

and this is my controller

```
[HttpPost]
        [Route("[area]/AddCar/{makeModel}/{milage}/{year}/{color}/{price}")]
        public IActionResult AddCar(String makeModel, String milage, String year, String color, String price)
        {
            Car car = new Car(year, makeModel, price, milage, color);

            return View();
        }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("[area]/AddCar")]
public IActionResult AddCar([FromForm] Car car)
{
    ...

    return View();
}
```

But the best practice is to use view model. Check this page
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: That looks like a cool way to do it. I ended up fixing it by removing the [Route("[area]/AddCar/{makeModel}/{milage}/{year}/{color}/{price}")] I guess they get posted automatically